# Swift "expected to decode Array<Any> but found a dictionary instead."

Tags: swift

I am using this code to fetch data from an API and setting some variables in my view controller and everything works fine. Since I am doing this in multiple controllers I am attempting to refactor the network call into a Service class using a completion handler to execute the necessary code for settings the view's variables. The service works fine on some of the controllers, but any controller that attempts to decode an array of objects, I get the error

> typeMismatch(Swift.Array, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Array but found a dictionary instead.", underlyingError: nil))

**Working**

```
let httpURL = "https://myurl.com/api"
guard let url = URL(string: httpURL) else { return }
var request = URLRequest(url: url)

request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
// Setting other headers here

let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in        
    guard let data = data else {return}        
        do {
            let consults = try JSONDecoder().decode([Consultation].self, from:data)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    // Settings values here
                    self.consultationTableView.reloadData()
                }            
            } catch let jsonErr {
                print(jsonErr)
            }        
        }
        task.resume()
}
```

**Not Working**

```
struct Service {
    static let sharedInstance = Service()

    func fetchPage(url: String, completion: @escaping (Data) -> ()){
        let httpURL = "https://myurl.com/api"

        guard let url = URL(string: httpURL) else { return }        
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        // Other headers here        
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in

            guard let data = data else {return}

            completion(data)

        }
        task.resume()
    }
}
```

**ViewController**

```
        let httpURL = "https://myUrl.com/api"
        Service.sharedInstance.fetchPage(url: httpURL) { (data) in
            do {
                let consults = try 
 ---> Error Happens>> JSONDecoder().decode([Consultation].self, from:data)                 } 
            } catch let jsonErr {
                print(jsonErr)
            }
        }
```

Any idea why when using the service class, the error shows up?

Comment: The error is pretty clear: You want (*Expected*) to decode an array (`[Consultation]`) but the real (*found*) type is a dictionary (without `[]`). I guess you ignored the root object. Without knowing the actual JSON it's a shot in the dark

Comment: We’d need to see an example of what the response looks like to advise further.